# OPC UA Subscription get DisplayName in Fast Handler

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

Currently I am shifting the DataAcquisition to Subscriptions. As there are multiple Values I want to observe, I create one Subscription with a set of MonitoredItems and use the FastDataChangeNotificationEventHandler. On Data changes the delegate/method gets called and I can get the new values without problems. But I cannot see to what Node the Value belongs to. How can I get that information?

The signature of the handler is

```cs
public static void FastHandler(Subscription subscription, 
            DataChangeNotification notification, IList<string> stringTable)
```

I find the updated value in `notification.MonitoredItems.ElementAt(i).Value.Value`, but in the element (Type `MonitoredItemNotification`) there is no DisplayName or Node ID allowing me to identify the Node, the value belongs to.

The parameter `subscription` holds information about the actual subscription, but does not tell, which nodes/items in it are updated.

So for example:
I am monitoring the Nodes A, B and C.
A and C change their values
I get a Call to the FastHandler as expected
In `notification.MonitoredItems` I find 2 Items, but no indication, what nodes there are linking to.

Am I missing something in here? How can I link those new values to the Nodes I am looking into?

I am using the reference .Net Implementation for OPC UA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from the reference implementation team helped me out:

The `notification.MonitoredItems` elements contain also a field `ClientHandle` - this `ClientHandle` maps the corresponding `subscription.MonitoredItems` element's `ClientHandle`.

Did costs me and colleagues many hours - hopefully this can help others out.